# PHP: Change Mention Link (Href)

Tags: php, string

Hello i find all Mention in string with this code:

```
$WebsiteURL = 'http://localhost/';
$mention_url = $WebsiteURL. "\\0";
$string = preg_replace("/(?<!\S)@([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/", "<a href='$mention_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

and when i click in Mention website redirect me to example: http://localhost/@nention_name

i want to change to redirect like this: http://localhost/nention_name

Comment: So, now, there is no change, and you need to change it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i need to change just link

Comment: Show us the original string, `$WebsiteURL`

Comment: $WebsiteURL = 'http://localhost/';

Comment: No idea if you want to extend your code (see https://ideone.com/tMMJyw) or just write a new one (see https://ideone.com/fOmprC)